# Align text in TableColumn /Paragraph

Tags: wpf, paragraph

It possible vertical  align text in TableColumn on middle?

I add  paragraph to the table cell of table. And this table I add to richTexBox control.
Problem is that middle column consists of  images(emoticons) and it is "align  to the  vertical center".

It’s difficult for me to describe it.

Here is an image:

[image]

I would like align first and third column vertical on the middle. I want text in this 3 columns on the same "level:.

Func which create Table with this 3 columns is here:

```
    public Table ConvertToTabRp(IRp rp, string avatarNick)
    {
        var tempRp = new Rp { RpText = rp.RpText, Nick = rp.Nick, Time = rp.Time, Your = rp.Your };

        if (tempRp.Your)
            tempRp.Nick = avatarNick;

        string time = string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0}", DateTime.ParseExact(tempRp.Time, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", null)
            .ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss").Replace("-", "."));

        var tab = new Table {Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0)};

        var gridLenghtConvertor = new GridLengthConverter();

        //1. col
        tab.Columns.Add(new TableColumn { Name = "colNick", Width = (GridLength)gridLenghtConvertor.ConvertFromString("100") });
        //2.col
        tab.Columns.Add(new TableColumn { Name = "colMsg", Width = (GridLength)gridLenghtConvertor.ConvertFromString("Auto") });
        //3.col
        tab.Columns.Add(new TableColumn { Name = "colDt", Width = (GridLength)gridLenghtConvertor.ConvertFromString("150") });

        tab.RowGroups.Add(new TableRowGroup());
        tab.RowGroups[0].Rows.Add(new TableRow());

        var tabRow = tab.RowGroups[0].Rows[0];

        //1.col - NICK
        var pNick = new Paragraph(new LineBreak()) { TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Left };
        pNick.Inlines.Add(new Run(tempRp.Nick));

        if (!tempRp.Your)
        {
            pNick.Foreground = Brushes.DodgerBlue;
        }
        tabRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(pNick));

        //2.col - MESSAGE
        tabRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(ConvertToRpWithEmoticons(tempRp.RpText)) { TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Left});

        //3.col  - DATE TIME
        var pTime = new Paragraph(new LineBreak()) { TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Right };
        pTime.Inlines.Add(time);
        tabRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(pTime));

        return tab;

    }
```

maybe solution can be:

```
        var pNick = new Paragraph(new LineBreak()) { TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Left , **VerticalTextAligment = Center** };
```

I don’t how vertical align in paragraph.

**EDIT:**

Maybe is problem in way how I add image to paragraph, here is it code:

```
            var image = new Image
            {
                Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(path, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)),
                Width = 20,
                Height = 20,
            };
            para.Inlines.Add(new Run(separatemsg.Text) { BaselineAlignment = BaselineAlignment.TextBottom });
            //insert smile
            para.Inlines.Add(new InlineUIContainer(image) {BaselineAlignment = BaselineAlignment.Bottom});
```

and this paragraph is add to 2. column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use the [BaselineAlignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.inline.baselinealignment.aspx)-property.
Use a [Run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.run.aspx)-Inline to put your text into the paragraphs and set the BaselineAlignment-property.

You can use this also for the image. Use for this the BaselineAlignment-property of the [InlineUIContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms522728.aspx)

Comment: I try set this property on InlineUiContainer which consist image, but it doesn’t help. It possible this property set na Paragrapg, or TableCell? I need set Vertical aligment on 1. and 3. column.

Comment: You have to set it on the inline. Use the Run-Inline for common text. Something like: Paragraph p=new Paragraph(new Run("MyText"){BaselineAlignment=BaselineAlignment.Center }) or blockElement.Inlines.Add(new Run("MyText"){BaselineAlignment=BaselineAlignment.Center });

Comment: Thank, I try it, but it doesn’t work. Maybe is problem in way how I add image to paragraph. I edited my question. On the bottom is code.